# File is having lots of special characters. How to replace?

Tags: shell-script, shell, files, vi, character-encoding

I have a file with record like:

```
CENTURY®KETTLEBELLS
COLEMANTT40°BAG
AlphaPro2¾TDLE
Lot™Stretch
M6×30
```

It shows normally in notepad files but in terminal when i cat it, it shows:

```
CENTURY▒KETTLEBELL
AlphaPro2▒TDLE
Lot▒Stretch
M6▒30
```

is there a way to fix this? I had to compare two files having these values. Due to ▒ everything is showing as a difference. Please help

**EDIT:**

This the file encoding:

```
$ file FULL_ITM.txt
FULL_ITM].txt: ascii text
$
```

This the output from locale command:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_US
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

Here's the result:

```
 LC_ALL=C od -c FULL_ITM.txt
0000000    C   E   N   T   U   R   Y 302 256   K   E   T   T   L   E   B
0000020    E   L   L   S  \n   C   O   L   E   M   A   N   T   T   4   0
0000040  302 260   B   A   G  \n   A   l   p   h   a   P   r   o   2 302
0000060  276   T   D   L   E  \n   L   o   t 342 204 242   S   t   r   e
0000100    t   c   h  \n   M   6 303 227   3   0  \n
0000113
```

Comment: This is a *[locale](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/locale)/encoding* issue. The terminal needs to be configured to use the same encoding as the file to display it the same way.

Comment: What encoding is the file using? (You may find that for a file called `list.txt` the command `file list.txt` will tell you.) What locale are you using? (The command `locale` should tell you.)

Comment: Hi @roamia, my file is ASCII and my locale is en_US.UTF-8

Comment: ASCII does not include characters like ¾ or ™ - if those are in the file, it's not using ASCII. Follow @roiama's instructions and post the output of `file <filename>`.

Comment: Hey @roaima, I have edited and added the commands. What should be the next steps? Please guide

Comment: It looks like the `file` command didn't look far enough to notice the non-ASCII characters. Try dumping the file's contents with `LC_ALL=C od -c FULL_ITM.txt`. This should show octal codes for the special characters, for example in UTF-8 encoding the "CENTURY®KETTLEB" part dumps as "`C   E   N   T   U   R   Y 302 256   K   E   T   T   L   E   B`" -- the "®" is encoded as octal `302 256` (which is hex `C2 AE`, which is UTF-8 for U+00AE, the registered sign). If you can show a few examples of readable characters and the corresponding octal codes, we can probably figure out the encoding.

Comment: If you paste `®` in the terminal, will it show `®` or `▒`? Maybe the terminal lacks glyphs for some characters and uses `▒` instead. What terminal (terminal emulator) are you using? Can you change the font?

Comment: Hi @Kamil & Gordan, i tried to convert the encoding: iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 FULL_ITM.txt > demo.txt , and the demo file does have '®' character but it removes other character like '™' and simple '-' hyphen.

Comment: Can you try other terminal emulator programs like `mate-terminal` or `gnome-terminal`?  You may need to install them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using an ISO-8859 locale, whereas the the file is UTF-8.

My suggestion would be to generate the corresponding UTF-8 locale for your system and use that (permanently) instead of your current one.

Unfortunately you didn't tell us your OS or Linux distribution, so here's how to configure the locale in Debian type systems

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

As root, choose the `en_US` one that includes UTF-8. Make it the default if it's your system

Comment: It's probably not the only issue. That `\302\256` is the encoding of `Â®` in iso8859-1. The fact that those two bytes are rendered as *one* substitution grapheme in the terminal suggests the terminal recognises it as  being  UTF-8 but cannot  display the corresponding character for some reason.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, yes.I can switch all of locale, terminal encoding, and terminal font around easily enough here, but I thought it might be worth taking it one step at a time. I can extend the answer if you think it more appropriate to do so for SE, but that's more into the realms of supposition than I generally like to head for an answer